# Regression tree in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm trying to implement a gradient tree boosting algorithm in matlab, but I need to control the number of terminal nodes (leaf nodes) in the regression tree. Is there a way to doing so with the classregtree in the statistics toolbox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pruning the tree. Matlab does pruning in two ways, by levels and by nodes. I prefer by levels so that you can specify the number of levels and it will prune it for you. 
The reason I pruned the tree is to avoid overfitting the tree, which happens if you have a large tree. The simple code for prune is

```
tprune = prune(tree,'level',p) ;
```

Where p is the number of levels. You can construct a for loop for 'p' so that it will keep pruning until your specifications are met.